# Delete a Entry in a textfile with batch

Tags: batch-file

If I for example use `findstr /g:Filters/test.ini < "ServerLogs/users.log" > "Logs/filtered_users.txt`

and I want to search first and write down the line and then remove/overwrite a line in for example the "ServerLogs/users.log"

What do I have to set?

e.g: "ServerLogs/users.log"

```
JacktheRiver IP:18.184.284.91 - SETPATHDOWN 394858913857869284 #10 39485918238584378
Laste3r IP:72.125.68.141 - SETPATHDOWN 346343253563467578 #22 35354634679795373
Rus48rr IP:63.215.154.23 - SETPATHDOWN 543534694689128453 #12 49348376384678221
TOkiN1 IP:54.132.146.41 - SETPATHDOWN 343543346363643644 #41 42395833891883585
```

Then take for example. `Rus48rr IP:63.215.154.23 - SETPATHDOWN 543534694689128453 #12 49348376384678221` and save it into the "filtered_users.txt". After remove this line out of the "ServerLogs/users.log" that it ends up like this:

```
JacktheRiver IP:18.184.284.91 - SETPATHDOWN 394858913857869284 #10 39485918238584378
Laste3r IP:72.125.68.141 - SETPATHDOWN 346343253563467578 #22 35354634679795373
TOkiN1 IP:54.132.146.41 - SETPATHDOWN 343543346363643644 #41 42395833891883585
```

Is this possible, If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

You can find matching lines with:

```
findstr /g:Filters/test.ini < "ServerLogs/users.log" > "Logs/filtered_users.txt"
```

and you can find lines that don't match with `/v` parameter:

```
findstr /g:Filters/test.ini /v < "ServerLogs/users.log" > "ServerLogs/users.tmp"
```

you can then overwrite `users.log` with the new `users.tmp` file.

Comment: I just want the line to disappear in the users.log after reading it out.

Comment: @user1984532 I don't think it's possible to do without a temporary file... and if you use a temporary file you have to be careful because there might be concurrency problems (eg. you extract filtered_users, then while you are copying your temporary file a new filtered user gets added to the log...)